# LinkedList pointer explanation

Tags: linked-list

So I get a little idea of how a linked list work and how the head node points to another node that contains data and also the address of the next node. I've also looked at examples. I've been looking at this code I found for the past five hours confused on how under the `display()` method that `current = head` points to the next node. I keep thinking `head.next = null` and doesn't point at the next node. Can someone explain to me how `head.next` is pointing to the next node or when did it acquired the address because I can't find when in the code it does.

```
public class SinglyLinkedList {    
    //Represent a node of the singly linked list    
    class Node{    
        int data;    
        Node next;    
            
        public Node(int data) {    
            this.data = data;    
            this.next = null;    
        }    
    }    
     
    //Represent the head and tail of the singly linked list    
    public Node head = null;    
    public Node tail = null;    
        
    //addNode() will add a new node to the list    
    public void addNode(int data) {    
        //Create a new node    
        Node newNode = new Node(data);    
            
        //Checks if the list is empty    
        if(head == null) {    
            //If list is empty, both head and tail will point to new node    
            head = newNode;    
            tail = newNode;    
        }    
        else {    
            //newNode will be added after tail such that tail's next will point to newNode    
            tail.next = newNode;    
            //newNode will become new tail of the list    
            tail = newNode;    
        }    
    }    
        
    //display() will display all the nodes present in the list    
    public void display() {    
        //Node current will point to head    
        Node current = head;    
            
        if(head == null) {    
            System.out.println("List is empty");    
            return;    
        }    
        System.out.println("Nodes of singly linked list: ");    
        while(current != null) {    
            //Prints each node by incrementing pointer    
            System.out.print(current.data + " ");    
            current = current.next;    
        }    
        System.out.println();    
    }    
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
            
        SinglyLinkedList sList = new SinglyLinkedList();    
            
        //Add nodes to the list    
        sList.addNode(1);    
        sList.addNode(2);    
        sList.addNode(3);    
        sList.addNode(4);    
            
        //Displays the nodes present in the list    
        sList.display();    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate through the linked list the first time, head points to the firstNode. Then as the while loop runs, the code updates the pointer("Current") to point to the next Node. This is shown where you see current = current.next; The loops keep running until current points to null, after which it ends. Hope you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that `head.next` is not directly assigned. However, `tail.next` is. Let's see what happens in `addNode()` for two cases:

1. When the list is empty and you add a node, both `head` and `tail` are set to the `newNode`. Keep in mind that (this being Java) `head` and `tail`  are *references* to the object `newNode`, that is, they reference the same object.
2. When there is already 1 element in the list, and you add a new node (the second one) you set `tail.next = newNode`. Now remember that `head` and `tail` are references to the same object (the first one added so far). They are basically two names for the same thing at this moment. So what really happens is that *the object referenced by `head` and `tail`* gets its `next` member set to `newNode` - and now both `head.next` and `tail.next` point to `newNode`. After that `tail` itself is made to reference tne `newNode` and at this moment `head` and `tail` start to reference different objects - `head` still referencing the first element, and `tail` now referencing the second (and so far last) element.

Now when you get to `display()`, you see that `head` is really a reference to the first element of the list, its `next` points to the second one and so on...

Comment: thank you for this Lyubomir! This really helped me understand now!